# Spring MVC - RequestMapping invalid prefix and view resolution

Tags: spring, servlets, spring-mvc, controller

I have a simple controller specified below,

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/add/*")
public class RequestMappingController {

    @Autowired
    private MathOps mathOps;

    @RequestMapping(value = "add2Operands", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String add(@RequestParam("op1") String op1, @RequestParam("op2") String op2, Model model) {
        int num1 = Integer.parseInt(op1);
        int num2 = Integer.parseInt(op2);
        int result = mathOps.add(num1, num2);

        model.addAttribute("op1", op1).addAttribute("op2", op2).addAttribute("result", result);

        return "adder";
    }    
}
```

This is my InteralViewResolver configuration

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="WEB-INF/views/"/>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
</bean>
```

and the adder.jsp file is directly under the /views folder.

When i navigate to

```
http://localhost:8080/mvc/add/add2Operands?op1=12&op2=2
```

i get a 404 error

```
/mvc/add/WEB-INF/views/adder.jsp
```

where "mvc" is my context path.

What am i doing wrong here?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try changing to:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/"/>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
</bean>
```

notice the "/" before WEB-INF